# Yum CentOS 7 server locally for repository and his HDD consumption

Tags: centos7, yum, repository

I want to install Yum repo server inside infrastructure shown in attached image.
[Yum architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcgUr.png).

My intensions are:

1. Install CentOS minimal inside *Secure Zone*
2. Computers in *Secure Zone* are not allowed to connect to *Internet*
3. Computers inside *Secure Zone* must have connection to update server which is inside *Open Zone*
4. Yum server which is located in *Open Zone* are allowed to go to mirrors in *Internet*
5. Between *Secure Zone*, *Open Zone* and *Internet* are two firewalls
6. Yum server inside *Open Zone* will get every day all new updates for CentOS 7
7. Computers in *Secure Zone* are updated manually and once a month

And now my questions:

1. How HDD disk space is needed in Yum server inside *Open Zone*? (only for CentOS 7 repo)
2. Will Yum server inside *Open Zone* collect all packages from internet or only that are needed for computers in *Secure Zone*? (For example in scenario when I have only one CentOS 7 minimal installation inside *Secure Zone*)
3. How fast the file size on Yum server will grow (eg. how many MB per month)?
4. What will happened with old packages when Yum server gets new version of package from internet. Will it be deleted (to preserve disk space) or it hold all versions with same package?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the scenario, you've described, should work. I'm doing similar thing with mirroring EPEL repos

In the open zone YUM server the repo space reservation differs on your requirements. If you decide to mirror just latest versions (-n parameter) some 30 GB should be sufficient (but better test!):

```
/usr/bin/reposync --repoid=CENTOS7 -n -p /data/yum
```

If your want full list of versions available in the repo, then you may get to much more and the required space will be growing (usuall increase rate can be ~4-5 GB per 3 months with bigger jump in case of minor version release). The command would be the same, just without -n:

```
/usr/bin/reposync --repoid=CENTOS7 -n -p /data/yum
```

Replace the repoid with real ones (CENTOS7 is just example).

Then you'll have to run createrepo on the mirrored repository. See the example:

```
/usr/bin/createrepo -d -s sha1 /data/yum/CENTOS7
```

If you want some retention, you may use -d parameter of reposync:

```
-d, --delete
       Delete local packages no longer present in repository.
```